# SUMO TraCI How to find the neighbouring junction?

Tags: sumo

I am using TraCI with SUMO recently. I am wondering, if there is a vehicle, how can I find the neighbouring (nearest) junctions around it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct TraCI function to get the nearest Junctions. However, you could store all the coordinates of all junctions in the network, and use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` to compute the `euclidean distances` between the vehicle and the junctions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to connectivity rather than airline distance you can simply walk along the edges of your current route and get the nodes as explained here: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Sumolib.html#import_a_network_and_retrieve_nodes_and_edges